# Sample space distinction

Tags: probability, sampling, sampling-theory

Suppose  a pair of dice is thrown 5 times then it's space space will be of the form-(123456,345255.....etc).Can we say that it is equivalent to tossing 1O dice simultaneously?If so ,can you tell me when this condition can happen where we can change the experiment to make it more simplified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One point in the sample space would be an outcome of all the rolls. That is, a single outcome might look like:
$$(1, 5), (2, 3), (2, 2), (5, 2), (3, 6)$$
and the full sample space would be the collection of *all* such things. You are correct that this is equivalent to just rolling 10 dice; to see this, just drop the parentheses in what I wrote above. I confess that I don't know what you mean when you say "tell me when this condition can happen where we can change the experiment to make it more simplified," though. If you can clarify, I'm happy to comment further.

Comment: I was talking about changing of the experiments i e in this example we can change tossing of two coins simultaneously to tossing 10 coins simultaneously. ON one glance they may look different but if we go deeper they are only one things.....how can we identify such sample spaces?

Comment: This would come from carefully considering the sample space (and its associated probabilities). Note that when I described dropping the parentheses above, this gives a way to rewrite the entire sample space in a different way where all the probabilities are preserved. At a base level, that's how you simplify sample spaces. But intuitively, you should ask yourself the question of if there is a meaningful difference between the two processes.

Comment: kay..this somewhat clears my doubt